# Cannot install a specific mysqlclient (2.0.3) version in conda under Win 64

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

Installed [Anaconda3 2023.03-1](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.03-1-Linux-x86_64.sh) (to match the Linux server install), and tried to create a virtual environment that has mysqlclient=2.0.3. Anaconda is installed for "All Users", so I ran Anaconda Prompt as Administrator to execute below commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda create -n venv01 mysqlclient=2.0.3
```

And I got an error message saying the package is not available:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mysqlclient=2.0.3

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

However, when I searched the [Anaconda package repo](https://anaconda.org), it is clearly available from the main and anaconda channel. Even if I force conda to install from anaconda:

```
conda create -n venv01 -c anaconda mysqlclient=2.0.3
```

I still the same error message.

Here is the search results:

[image]

I did have older Anaconda 2020.10 that I recently uninstalled, and I did check to make sure the uninstall was clean.

So why am I getting this error? FYI, I also tried Anaconda 2022.10 and 2023.07 and they gave me the same error.

By the way, under Anaconda 2023.03, if I do not specify version for mysqlclient, I will get 1.13.14 installed - which I assume is the highest version conda can find.

Comment: Would you show us the command you ran, the error message, and relevant config files?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Schwern by "relevant config files" - do you mean the output of `conda config --show`? As the output of this command is rather detailed. Or do you mean the content of the file .condarc? .condarc looks like `channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
ssl_verify: true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the search result, as the version listed in your screenshot is the most recent version for any platform, but not every version is available for every platform.

If you go one page deeper to https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mysqlclient you will see

[image]

Note that  `win-64 v1.3.14` is the most recent win64 version. 2.0.3 is only availabel for linux-64, osx-arm64 and linux-ppc64le

Comment: Thanks! I thought I filtered my results with win-64 that should have done the trick. Guess not.

Comment: so sounds like my only option is to install use pip in the virtual env - which is something I was trying to avoid, as I had issues with mixing conda and pip before.

Comment: yes, create a conda env and install there if you need that specific version